# CarrierWave customize original filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

I am attempting to customize the original filename for an image uploaded through CarrierWave by appending some sort of [unique UUID](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files). The problem is that I do not want this UUID to also be appended onto the subsequent version names.

The objective here is I want the original file to be secured by obscurity. So a user cannot just take `"thumb_image.jpg"` and access the original `"image.jpg"` simply by removing `"thumb_"`. Something like this would be the goal:

- `"00000001-image.jpg"` (original)
- `"thumb-image.jpg"` (version 1)
- `"small-thumb-image.jpg"` (version 2)
- etc.

I cannot seem to find a way to get this integrated quite right using the following wiki docs:

- https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files
- https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Customize-your-version-file-names

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems i was able to get this working with the following approach:

```
def filename
  "#{secure_token}_#{original_filename.chomp(File.extname(super))}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
end

version :thumb do
  process convert: 'jpg'

  def full_filename(for_file = file)
    "#{model.id}_thumb.jpg"
  end
end

protected

def secure_token
  var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
  model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
end
```